# Page always focussing bottom tab container

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

In page bottom I have few tab panels, when page loads its focussing my bottom tab panel but when I provide property - **Enabled = false** then it loads properly but again an issue, in tabcontainer controls all disabled

Comment: Could you show some of your code please ?

Comment: <asp:TabContainer ID="TabContainerBottom1" Enabled="false" runat="server">
I have 3 panel in bottom of the page. inside this container

Comment: Best to edit your question and paste all the code that relates to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Surely if you will disable the tab container, it will also disable all the contents. If on page load, you want to focus some other control like a textbox, then write following code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

{

    textBox.Focus();      

}
```

or

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {       

      Page.SetFocus(textBox);

    }
```

Here `textBox` is the control id